# Busqueda BInaria de cadena tipo chart con gets y sin usar strcmp

Tags: c

necesito ayuda con este ejercicio:
Leer una cadena desde teclado, y posteriormente leer una palabra desde teclado. Buscar la palabra leída en la cadena y decir si se encontró o no (no utilizar función strstr).

llevo mas de 2 semanas intentando hacerlo, pero no me sale, ayuda por favor.

Este es el codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define cadena 256


    int main() {
        char nombre[cadena][256];
        char vector[cadena][5];
        int x;
        for (x=1;x<=5;x+=1) {
            printf("Ingresa las Palabras %i\n",x);
            gets(vector[x-1]);
            //scanf("%s",vector[x-1]);
        }
        printf("Ingresa las Palabras a buscar\n");
        scanf("%s",nombre);
        for (x=1;x<=5;x+=1) {
            if (strcmp(nombre,vector[x-1])==0) {
                printf("La Palabra %s se encuentra en la posicion %i\n",nombre,x);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

al momento de digitar una palbra que contiene espacios, la quiero buscar y ahi tiene error. ademas que no debo ocupar strcmp

Gracias

Comment: No digas que llevas más de dos semanas intentado, comparte el código que has realizado estas dos semanas. De lo contrario parece que solo quieres que te resuelvan la tarea y eso no es bien visto en el sitio.

Comment: tienes mucha razón,una disculpa, ya comparti el código, muchas gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 0):

Es muy conveniente espaciar el código para tener cierta claridad, y menos posibilidades de cometer errores, causados por generar una cofusión añadida.

Poner las llaves a nivel vertical correlativo, entre sí, ayuda también muchísimo a clarificar un desarrollo.

Mientras no sea otro el resultado, definitivamente ..

Poner a las variables nombres descriptivos, ayuda a no generar errores de uso de concepto de variable, tipo y tamaño equivocado al programar.

En el arrays de 2 dimensiones de caracteres *`vector`*, pusiste las dimesiones en orden inverso.

Los bucles *`for`*, también estaba complejo, el contador x lo inicializas en 1, pero luego le restas 1 para tener el indice 0.

Si necesitas usar eso así, perfecto, pero no es el caso. Y en consecuencia, es una equivalencia compleja, que genera cierta ineficiencia en el código. Un codigo correcto más corto y sencillo, es mas directo, está más depurado y compila un ejecutable más rápido, por principio.

*A cerca de la claridad con uno mismo, quien programa. Para comprender, depurar y programar de forma precisa.*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define strSize 256

int main()
    {
    char nombre[strSize];
    char vector[5][strSize];
    
    int ind, x = 0;

    nombre[0] = '\0';

    printf("Ingresa las palabras, patrones de busqueda ..\n");

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
        {
        printf("\n %i :  ", x);
        gets(vector[x]);
        }

    printf("\n\nIngresa la cadena, modelo de busqueda .. \n\n      ");

    gets(nombre);
    
    printf_s("\n");
    
    for (short previo = 0, x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
        ind = 0;

        while (ind < strlen(nombre))
            {
            while (ind <= strlen(nombre) && vector[x][0] != nombre[ind]) ind++;

            if (ind < strlen(nombre) && vector[x][0] == nombre[ind])
                {
                previo = ind;

                while ((size_t)(ind - (int)previo) <= strlen(vector[x]) && ind < strlen(nombre) && vector[x][ind - previo] == nombre[ind])
                        ind++;

                if ((size_t)(ind - (int)previo) == strlen(vector[x]))
                    printf_s("\nLa Palabra %s se encuentra en la posicion %i\n", vector[x], previo);
                }
            }
        }

    fflush(stdin);
    getch(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]